# Protecting an endpoint with AD and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently trying to authenticate users for a web app with our domain AD and so far I have been able to successfully login.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var authService = new ADAuthenticationService(AuthenticationManager);

    var authenticationResult = authService.SignIn(model.Email, model.Password);

    if (authenticationResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        // To home/index since no returnUrl is actually being captured for now
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", authenticationResult.ErrorMessage);
    return View(model);
}
```

My auth service creates a claim identity and signs the user in. Next, I want to secure my web api endpoints to allow only logged in clients to send requests to it. Following an example I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorize()
{
    var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(User).Claims.ToArray();
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer");
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

However, when I actually try to go to the endpoint it tells me I am unauthorized. In the request headers I have "Authorization: Bearer *token here*".

EDIT:
In Startup.Auth.cs I have auth configured as such

```
static Startup()
{
    PublicClientId = "web";

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };
}
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
         AuthenticationType = ADAuthentication.ApplicationCookie,
         LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
         Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
         {
              OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
              regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
         },
         CookieName = "MyAppAuthenticationType",
         CookieHttpOnly = true,
         ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    });
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
}
```

EDIT 2:
ADAuthenticationService.cs

```
public ADAuthenticationService(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
{
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}


public AuthenticationResult SignIn(String username, String password)
{
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(authenticationType);
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;
    try
    {
        userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, username);
        if (userPrincipal != null)
        {
            isAuthenticated = principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        return new AuthenticationResult("Username or Password is not correct");
    }

    /* some other invalid login results here */

    var identity = CreateIdentity(userPrincipal);

    authenticationManager.SignOut(ADAuthentication.ApplicationCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);


    return new AuthenticationResult();
}


private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(UserPrincipal userPrincipal)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ADAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userPrincipal.SamAccountName));
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipal.EmailAddress))
    {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userPrincipal.EmailAddress));
    }

    var groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
    foreach (var @group in groups)
    {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, @group.Name));
    }

    return identity;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you configured authentication on the web api. Also, that `Authorize` action should really be an `HttpPost` instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've added in my configuration!

Comment: Ok, I get it that you are creating the tokens yourself. Can you add that code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure where the token is being generated - I scaffolded a new project in VS2017 and it came with the basic OWIN OAuth setup and I swapped out the login logic to verify against my AD instead of my computer's local credentials. I'll include the code for my AD login logic.

Comment: When you say you are passing "Authorization: Bearer token here", from where are you obtaining that token?

Comment: I've been trying to trace through the scaffolded code and I can't seem to find where the bearer token is being created. I only see where it's being passed into the headers on the front-end. Any ideas where it would be?